# Finding all the number of ip addresses used in eks with fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc

I am trying to understand the usage of the ip addresses from my vpc in the eks with fargate environment. I can see that each pod has its own private ip address, which seems to be the same ip address for fargate node as well. It seems that the ENI allocates a single primary address for a EC2 node and [many ip address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html) as secondary based on the [size](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/blob/master/docs/eni-and-ip-target.md), but I cannot find the same information on fargate. Does that mean it does not have any secondary ip addresses allocated ?

Extending on the question, it seems that a [network load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network-load-balancing.html) requires a minimum of 8 free ip addressses to be created, Does that mean it blocks all the 8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...Does that mean it does not have any secondary ip addresses allocated ?`

Correct, since you can only run 1 pod on each Fargate instance, while on EC2 node you can run many pods.

`...Does that mean it blocks all the 8 ?`

The LB controller won't block subnet IP. When you make request to create NLB in a subnet that has insufficient IP, you will see error message like: `..."error":"InvalidSubnet: Not enough IP space available in subnet-.... ELB requires at least 8 free IP addresses in each subnet`. Note this is a requirement of ELB and not EKS.

Comment: That sums up the count, thank you